# How do I properly fix deploy permission issues with Hudson and ant?

Tags: java, ant, permissions, hudson, deployment

I'm having trouble deploying my Web start to the web server due to permissions problems (reformatted):

```
/home/hudson/.../build/build-web-start.xml:20: Failed to copy
/home/hudson/.../dist/app.jnlp to 
/var/development/.../webstart/app.jnlp due to java.io.FileNotFoundException
/var/development/.../webstart/app.jnlp (Permission denied) 
and I couldn't delete the corrupt /var/development/.../webstart/app.jnlp
```

...so it's obvious what the problem is.  I need to do one of the following:

- Find the build user so that I can give it permissions
- Configure hudson to build the app under a specific user (perhaps separating the deploy from the rest of the build)
- Configure the ant build script to execute the deploy under a specific user.

Current situation:

- I'm running Hudson under jetty
- I've given the jetty user group permissions to be able to write to the deploy folder
- HUDSON_HOME is set to /home/hudson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `etc/init.d/jetty` startup script contains the line (by default)

```
JETTY_USER=jetty
```

so...

```
chown jetty /var/development/.../webstart -R
```

does the trick.

NB: In particular, this highlights that setting jetty's group permissions to be able to write to the directory is not enough: jetty runs it's context under jetty:**nogroup**; e.g. it has no group.